# NoClassDefFoundError error when running locally only

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, servlets, web

Im getting the following error below

Ive added the following dependency and the code compiles...Im getting this even when commenting out the code where the error says its failing....

It woks when I deploy on Heroku but fails when running locally....

Any idea? Im lost....

My dependency:

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sendgrid</groupId>
        <artifactId>sendgrid-java</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Look the errors in Maven console. It seems dependency not getting downloaded to your classpath. 
If its downloading, try cleaning and building again.

Also try maven update settings.

Comment: Im using Intelij. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your local maven repository is broken. You may try below:

1. Go to your [local Maven repository](https://www.mkyong.com/maven/where-is-maven-local-repository/) to check if the artifact is downloaded or not. It may be that the the artifact was not downloaded at all or not downloaded fully/correctly;
2. If you can find the `sendgrid` dir in your local maven repository, try delete the dir and execute `mvn clean install` (or `mvn clean idea:idea`), this should force maven to re-download the artifact.

Comment: @user1163234 `NoClassDefFoundError` happens _when a particular class is present at compile time, but was missing at run time_ (see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError.html)). What this means is that when you run the project, the artifact is not included in the run time. You can check your server configuration and see if you can find the artifact under both `library` and `artifacts` of the project that you're running. If you can't find it, add it manually should resolve your issue.

Comment: @user1163234 forgot to mention, also check _Modules_ -> the module that depends on the artifact -> _Dependencies_ tab.